# C# TableLayoutPanel Issues while resizing my Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, tablelayoutpanel, responsiveness

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYqSe.png)i am trying to make a responsive design for my c# WinForm Project.

I have a MainForm that contains TableLayoutPanel.

TableLayoutPanel contains 2 columns and a single row.
Columns are 20% and 80% respectively.
Row is set to occupy 100%.

Column 1 has another TableLayoutPanel within, containing 3 rows and a single column.

Column 2 should show UserControl i have created and it does, until i resize it (maximize the MainForm)

Can someone help me with the issue i am having.

Here's a screenshot to better understand what i am having issues with.
It creates a gap between Column1 Content and Column2 Content.

Button1 of UserControl has anchor left-top and is position properly on the UserControl.

I have tried changing all the properties of Form,TableLayout and userControl but nothing seems to help.
There is no padding with any of my controls/layouts.

ScreenShots of the issue:https://imgur.com/a/2vuDbJM

```
namespace eProdavnica
{
    partial class FormMain
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        ///  Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        ///  Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        ///  the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            TreeNode treeNode1 = new TreeNode("Kasa");
            TreeNode treeNode2 = new TreeNode("Sifarnik Artikla");
            TreeNode treeNode3 = new TreeNode("Sifarnik Partnera");
            TreeNode treeNode4 = new TreeNode("Sifarnik", new TreeNode[] { treeNode2, treeNode3 });
            tableLayoutPanel1 = new TableLayoutPanel();
            tableLayoutPanel2 = new TableLayoutPanel();
            labelBaza = new Label();
            treeViewMeni = new TreeView();
            labelKorisnik = new Label();
            tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
            tableLayoutPanel2.SuspendLayout();
            SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // tableLayoutPanel1
            // 
            tableLayoutPanel1.AutoSize = true;
            tableLayoutPanel1.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
            tableLayoutPanel1.BackColor = SystemColors.ControlDark;
            tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 2;
            tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 17F));
            tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 83F));
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(tableLayoutPanel2, 0, 0);
            tableLayoutPanel1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            tableLayoutPanel1.GrowStyle = TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.FixedSize;
            tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            tableLayoutPanel1.Margin = new Padding(0);
            tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 1;
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100F));
            tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new Size(1384, 761);
            tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // tableLayoutPanel2
            // 
            tableLayoutPanel2.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left;
            tableLayoutPanel2.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
            tableLayoutPanel2.BackColor = SystemColors.ButtonHighlight;
            tableLayoutPanel2.ColumnCount = 1;
            tableLayoutPanel2.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100F));
            tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(labelBaza, 0, 1);
            tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(treeViewMeni, 0, 2);
            tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(labelKorisnik, 0, 0);
            tableLayoutPanel2.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            tableLayoutPanel2.Margin = new Padding(0);
            tableLayoutPanel2.Name = "tableLayoutPanel2";
            tableLayoutPanel2.RowCount = 3;
            tableLayoutPanel2.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 30F));
            tableLayoutPanel2.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 25F));
            tableLayoutPanel2.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle());
            tableLayoutPanel2.Size = new Size(232, 761);
            tableLayoutPanel2.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // labelBaza
            // 
            labelBaza.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right;
            labelBaza.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            labelBaza.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 14F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);
            labelBaza.ForeColor = Color.Crimson;
            labelBaza.Location = new Point(0, 30);
            labelBaza.Margin = new Padding(0);
            labelBaza.Name = "labelBaza";
            labelBaza.Size = new Size(232, 25);
            labelBaza.TabIndex = 3;
            labelBaza.Text = "Baza";
            labelBaza.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            // 
            // treeViewMeni
            // 
            treeViewMeni.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            treeViewMeni.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            treeViewMeni.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 12F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);
            treeViewMeni.Location = new Point(0, 65);
            treeViewMeni.Margin = new Padding(0, 10, 0, 0);
            treeViewMeni.Name = "treeViewMeni";
            treeNode1.Name = "Node0";
            treeNode1.Text = "Kasa";
            treeNode2.Name = "Node2";
            treeNode2.Text = "Sifarnik Artikla";
            treeNode3.Name = "Node3";
            treeNode3.Text = "Sifarnik Partnera";
            treeNode4.Name = "Node1";
            treeNode4.Text = "Sifarnik";
            treeViewMeni.Nodes.AddRange(new TreeNode[] { treeNode1, treeNode4 });
            treeViewMeni.Size = new Size(232, 715);
            treeViewMeni.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // labelKorisnik
            // 
            labelKorisnik.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right;
            labelKorisnik.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            labelKorisnik.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 14F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);
            labelKorisnik.ForeColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
            labelKorisnik.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            labelKorisnik.Margin = new Padding(0);
            labelKorisnik.Name = "labelKorisnik";
            labelKorisnik.Size = new Size(232, 30);
            labelKorisnik.TabIndex = 1;
            labelKorisnik.Text = "Korisnik";
            labelKorisnik.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomLeft;
            // 
            // FormMain
            // 
            AutoScaleDimensions = new SizeF(7F, 15F);
            AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;
            AutoSize = true;
            AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
            ClientSize = new Size(1384, 761);
            Controls.Add(tableLayoutPanel1);
            MinimumSize = new Size(1400, 800);
            Name = "FormMain";
            RightToLeftLayout = true;
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            Text = "eProdavnica - Main";
            Load += FormMain_Load;
            tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            tableLayoutPanel2.ResumeLayout(false);
            ResumeLayout(false);
            PerformLayout();
        }

        #endregion

        private TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1;
        private TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel2;
        private Label labelBaza;
        private Label labelKorisnik;
        private TreeView treeViewMeni;
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace eProdavnica
{
    partial class UserControl1
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            button1 = new Button();
            button2 = new Button();
            SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            button1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            button1.Margin = new Padding(0);
            button1.Name = "button1";
            button1.Size = new Size(128, 47);
            button1.TabIndex = 0;
            button1.Text = "button1";
            button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            button2.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;
            button2.Location = new Point(1025, 566);
            button2.Margin = new Padding(0);
            button2.Name = "button2";
            button2.Size = new Size(128, 47);
            button2.TabIndex = 1;
            button2.Text = "button2";
            button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // UserControl1
            // 
            AutoScaleDimensions = new SizeF(96F, 96F);
            AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Dpi;
            AutoSize = true;
            AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
            Controls.Add(button2);
            Controls.Add(button1);
            Margin = new Padding(0);
            Name = "UserControl1";
            Size = new Size(1153, 613);
            ResumeLayout(false);
        }

        #endregion

        private Button button1;
        private Button button2;
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't provided any screenshots and you haven't provided any code. Show us the designer code. You'll have to Show All Files in the Solution Explorer to be able to open that.

Comment: Hey @jmcilhinney thanks for reply, i have added both screenshots of the issue and link to github's project code

Comment: Don't post pictures of or links to code. Post the relevant code as text, formatted as code. Please spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to ask a question correctly. It would also help to see a screenshot of the designer, which will show the cell borders in the `TableLayoutPanels`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i am unsure what part of code exactly is causing this to happen. That's the reason i have uploaded the project as a whole to github. 
Updating my question with designers code now. Thanks for guiding me and answering in the first place. :)

Comment: Added the designers @jmcilhinney, i am still not allowed to embed images, so there's a link to imgur

Answer (score -1):

I was noob enough to set % for column width, so once maximized, column 1 would occupy more space while its content did not follow,i have fixed the issue by making my column 1 absolute size and column 2 to 100% of the space available.
Hope this helps to any newbie out there